# Web videos not playing at random times of the day

Tags: video

This problems happens randomly, initially only YouTube videos didn't play, the page opens but the spinning buffer symbol appears and the video doesn't load and play but at that time I could play Twitch and Coursera lectures. But since yesterday, when this problem occurs, videos don't play on any site, including Twitch, Coursera, etc, this problem is random, at other times I can play them without problem.

Since yesterday, outlook.com is also not loading.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your temporary internet files? Also, is this on your home network? If so, have your powercycled your router or modem?

Comment: I use Firefox and I configured it to clear everything when I close it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm only experiencing this on Fedora 24, I haven't checked it on Windows 7 but this problem is not there on my phone.

Comment: Your phone communicates differently with servers. It's still worthwhile rebooting your home network devices. Also, your phone not having the issue would mean it is not the ISP.

Comment: Just now tried turning off and on the router, didn't resolve the problem. Only YouTube, Outlook, Twitch and Coursera seem to be effected by this, others have no problem.

Comment: Seems to be a security certificate issue, I can access mail.live.com. I don't about videos not playing issue.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? If you're using Chrome, try Firefox, or vice versa.